# Problem in columns fetched PowerBI API audit log

Tags: azure, api, powerbi, powerbi-api

I have been using PowerBI API to fetch the Audit log of PowerBI usages. From past 15 days, I was getting different column list previously BUT currently I am getting less columns from API itself.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

**Details (API to fetch the data):**

[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime='2023-03-12T00:00:00.000Z'&endDateTime='2023-03-12T23:59:59.999Z'](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime=%272023-03-12T00:00:00.000Z%27&endDateTime=%272023-03-12T23:59:59.999Z%27)

**For API authentication I am using the following URL:**

https://login.microsoftonline.com/<ApplicationID_of_Azure_APP_Registered>/oauth2/token

**Body for above URL:**

grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api&client_id=<Client_ID_OF_APP>&client_secret=<Client_Secret_OF_APP>

**Content-Type:**  application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Screenshots for column list are attached below (Previously and Now):**

***Previously:***

[image]

***Now:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application** and granted API permissions:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
resource:https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

By using the above token, I tried to **fetch API to get audit logs** like below:

```json
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime='2023-03-12T00:00:00.000Z'&endDateTime='2023-03-12T23:59:59.999Z'
```

Check this **MsDoc** to check the sample output : [Admin - Get Activity Events - REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/get-activity-events#get-audit-activity-events-within-a-time-window-example)

[image]

By **default** based on the size, the response will be in the below form:

```json
{
"activityEventEntities": [],
"continuationUri": null,
"continuationToken": null,
"lastResultSet": true
}
```

- When obtaining large amounts of data from an API, such as audit logs in Power BI, continuation tokens and URIs are generated.
- In this scenario, the API will generate a continuation token and URI that can be used to retrieve the next batch of data.